# Scalable networks

Tags: networking, scalability

I'm designing a game server and I'm stuck on how to design the network in such a way that scales..

First of all, should the servers be connected some how (how?) or should they poll a database in the backend to get messages?

Any books or websites would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am by no means an expert on this subject, but I think a common solution is to use different server instances for different physically divided areas of a game and have hand-offs between them when players move. I also suspect that certain actions like inventory management might even go through a different server in order to provide some measure of transaction safety and monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Red Dwarf Server](http://www.reddwarfserver.org/) project. It's written in Java and is very scalable.

The team at Sun was working on multi-node support (e.g. to dynamically move clients between server nodes, etc.) but then Oracle came and dropped the project. It's open source now.

Check out their design docs and the code. You'll learn a lot!